# why kafka-console-producer only write message to 1 partition(topic has 3 partitions) instead of using round-robin algorithm?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using the kafka 3.3.2.
I have create one topic with 3 partitions.From the below screenshot we can see there are 3 folders
[image]

Then I use the kafka-console-producer to write message to this topic. The messages are {message+i} format:
for example: message1, message2, message3 etc.

However when I check the log file I find that all the message are sent to partition0 in /tmp/kafka-logs/my-partitioned-topic-0/00000000000000000000.log

There is not content in /tmp/kafka-logs/my-partitioned-topic-**1**/00000000000000000000.log

Do you know the reason?

Thanks for explaination.

Please help me understand the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka uses a Sticky partitioning strategy for non-keyed records to address the problem of spreading out records without keys into smaller batches.
So, i'm guessing that you are sending your messages without a key.
You can get more information on these strategy and when kafka uses Round-Robin in this: [article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-producer-improvements-sticky-partitioner/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I am sending messages without key. Your answer is helpful. After I submitted this question, I tried to send more messages and found data in topic1 finally. Your article is helpful. Thanks again.